# Ruby or Rails find records dated "two months from now"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, date-range

I am trying to find all records in a given month that is roughly  2 months from "now"--now being when a task will run.  For instance...if the task runs February 1, it should find ALL records expiring in April.  However, if the task runs February 4, it should also, only find all records expiring in April (including April 1, 2, 3...etc).

I can get the below query to work (I'm setting a monthly cron job for this task)....EXCEPT it doesn't work when run in November or December.

```
def expiring_soon 

future_date = Date.today + 30.days
first_date = Date.new(future_date.year, future_date.month, 1)
last_date = Date.new(future_date.year, future_date.month + 1.month) - 1.day
@expiring = SampleRecord.expires_between(first_date, last_date)
```

I feel like there has to be a better way....I'm using Rails 4 and Postgres

Comment: Have you looked at the rails helpers for dates such as `beginning_of_month`, `months_since`, `end_of_month`, `next_month` etc.? [DateAndTime::Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-months_since). These seem to be what you are looking for e.g. `first_date = Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month` and `last_date = first_date.end_of_month`  possibly? BTW this is only a 1 month range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your model:

```
scope :expiring_soon, -> {
  date = Date.today >> 1
  where(expires_at: (date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month))
}
```

And then call the scope like this:

```
YourModel.expiring_soon
```

You might want to read about [Date/Time calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html) and [Range queries (see 2.3.2)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) in Rails.

Comment: While I endorse this answer as it stands right now February will return March not April because you are only advancing 30 days. As per the post February should return April. (I know the OP code will do the same but shouldn't based on the description)

Comment: yes, it should be based on months, not days as per OP needs. But the logic is sound.   it should be changed to:     ````date = Date.today + 2.months````

Comment: @engineersmnky : You were right. I fixed that problem by using Ruby's [`Date#>>`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) method that handles such edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would want something like this. Use the `first_date` as a starting point for `last_date`

```
future_date = Date.today + 30.days
first_date = Date.new(future_date.year, future_date.month, 1)
last_date = first_date.end_of_month # i.e. return 23:59:59 Dec 31st
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have got `run_at` field in your `Job` model, and `expires_at` field in your `SampleRecord` model. So for particular `job` you can do something like:

```
SampleRecord.where("expires_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", job.run_at, job.run_at + 2.months)
```